# Regex only detects the first emoticon?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a regular expression I am using to detect all of emoticons in a text:

```
/[\:][0-9A-Za-z'\&\-\.\/()=:;]/.exec(" Hi there:d :p")
```

But it only detects the first (:d)
Where is the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: End the expression with `/g` for it to match more than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and regex with global `g` flag:

```
"Hi there:d :p".match(/[\:][0-9A-Za-z'\&\-\.\/()=:;]/g);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the global `g` flag

```
[\:][0-9A-Za-z'\&\-\.\/()=:;]/g
```

without this modifier, the regex will stop at the first occurrence (if any)

Comment: It won't really help, since `exec` should be used iteratively.